# WordPress: How to set Yoast SEO params for all pages of a certain category?

Tags: php, wordpress, yoast

Well, I have an issue with the Yoast SEO plug-in on WordPress. I want to configure a template of SEO settings (meta title and meta description) that will be applied for all pages from a certain category.

Actually, Yoast SEO allows users to configure SEO settings for all "category" pages, but it's not my point. My point is to have something like that, customizable from Back-Office.

What Yoast SEO allows now:

```
if ( is_category() ) {

    //meta title
    //meta description

}
```

What I'm expecting for :

```
if ( in_category('cars') ) {

    //meta title = Cars
    //meta description = We talking about cars

} elseif ( in_category('bikes') ) {

    //meta title = Bikes
    //meta description = We talking about bikes

}
```

---

I don't want this (which is the native setting):

**What Yoast SEO allows now**

[image: What Yoast SEO allows now]

To be really clear, I want to add this to Yoast SEO plug-in:

**What I'm expecting for**

[image: What I'm expecting for]

Comment: Did you check their [API](https://yoast.com/wordpress/plugins/seo/api/)?

Comment: I did, but it looks like it doesn't help for my issue..

Comment: Did you check these filters: 1. `wpseo_title` 2. `wpseo_metadesc`?

Comment: Yes, as I told you, I did

Comment: You have 2 categories namely *Cars* and *Bikes*. You would like to change the title and meta descriptions for the archive pages of only these 2 categories; right?

Comment: I want all the "cars" pages to have a certain SEO setup, lets say title

%A% - %B%

and want all the "bikes" pages to have an other SEO setup, lets say title

%C% - %D%

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *all the "cars" pages*? Is it all the pages of car category? e.g. 1. http://yourwebsite.com/category/cars/ 2. http://yourwebsite.com/category/cars/page/2/ 3. http://yourwebsite.com/category/cars/page/3/

Comment: What i mean by "cars" pages :
site.com/cars/page1
site.com/cars/page2
site.com/cars/page3

What i mean by "bikes" pages :
site.com/bikes/page1
site.com/bikes/page2
site.com/bikes/page3

Comment: Just want to understand your exact requirement. `site.com/cars/page1` is a category *archive page* that shows all the posts from *Cars* category. Right?

Comment: Not at all ah ah, ok i think i explain really badly..

Comment: Nothing to worry! It can happen. Can you share the link where we can see the pages in action?

Comment: Actually, i'm working in local.. but well, i'm gonna add some details in the post check it out ;)

Comment: Do you understand better with the screenshots @KashifRafique ?

Comment: You can achieve the end results using the earlier mentioned filters, but it can't be controlled and visible in Yoast SEO option as shown in your screenshot. Let me know if you are OK with the code.

Comment: I think i'm ok with just using the mentioned filter, but as i'm working for a client, i need to find a dynamical solution, customizable from the BO.. 

So, I'll have to get throuht it thanks to the mentioned filter, but also add a "window" in the BO as my screenshot. I think that this last part will be the harder..

Comment: Yes, it's bit harder. I dug up their code and found `wpseo_option_tab-metas_taxonomies` filter. You may use it to customizing the **Yoast Taxonomy Meta** options.

Comment: I'll try, thank you very much for helping, I'm also tying to use the solution of @PhpDoe :)

Answer (score 0):

I maybe have a solution that can satisfy you : it's about creating a custom template variable customizable from the Back-Office (customizable on each category) with a free plugin called Metabox. In this case, Metabox and YOAST SEO are working together.

You have the whole tutorial here : https://metabox.io/add-custom-fields-to-yoast-seo-meta-tags/ (read it from "Creating custom template variables").

Two main steps :

1/ You create your Custom Field with Metabox.

2/ You use the Custom Template variable on your YOAST SEO Pannel to display in source code what the customer will write (directly on each category page from the back-office).

If I understand you clear and loud (and your last comment), you want your customer to personalize easily the title tag and meta description tag depending the different category.

So i'm 90% sure this solution does the job !

(I've read on Yoast Forum, from a Yoast Team member, that the sustainability of what you want to do (customizing Yoast Plugin) is uncertain. Meaning : it could not work after updating the plugin, etc.)

Hope it helps !

Comment: Hi @PhpDoe thanks for your answer ! I’ll try this and i tell you ! :)